# Ensure that enum corresponds to a certain template type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to map data types from a file to memory, so I have a class which takes the information for each column.
Different types have different mapping parameters, so I created a struct with the appropriate parameters for each supported type. I managed to solve the problem of having typesafety this way, and now I'm using a template for i.e. numeric types which all share the same attributes, and only the type differs.
The only thing that is is still rather ugly, is that I can not assign the correct enum simply based on the supported type alone.

As is shown in the example below, in case of a numeric type I manually have to assign the associated type (`c5` and `c6` in the example code). Now I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution, so that I can use some template technique (`enable_if`?)to select the correct enum value based on the supported type alone (`c7` is the intended target example).

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 which supports a subset of C+11.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <time.h>

#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

typedef char byte_t;
typedef unsigned char ubyte_t;
typedef short word_t;
typedef unsigned short uword_t;
typedef unsigned short date_t;

typedef char string_t;

class ColumnDef
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        T_UNDEFINED,

        T_byte,
        T_ubyte,
        T_word,
        T_uword,
        T_size_t,
        T_string,
        T_std_string,
        T_date_string,
        T_date,

        T_MAX
    } ColumnDefType;

    typedef enum
    {
        DF_UNDEFINED,

        DF_TTMMYY,
        DF_YYMMTT,
        DF_TTMMYYYY,
        DF_YYYYMMTT,
        DF_TT_MM_YYYY,
        DF_YYYY_MM_TT,

        DF_MAX
    } DateFormat;

    class cstring_type
    {
    public:
        ColumnDefType Type;

        const char *Adress;
        size_t MaxLen;
        static cstring_type init(const char *p, size_t nMaxLen) { cstring_type t = {T_string, p, nMaxLen}; return t; };
    };

    class cpp_string_type
    {
    public:
        ColumnDefType Type;

        std::string *Adress;
        static cpp_string_type init(std::string *p) { cpp_string_type t = {T_std_string, p}; return t; };
    };

    class ubyte_type
    {
    public:
        ColumnDefType Type;

        ubyte_t *Adress;
        ubyte_t Default;
        static ubyte_type init(ubyte_t *p, ubyte_t nDef) { ubyte_type t = {T_ubyte, p, nDef}; return t; };
    };

    class date_type
    {
    public:
        ColumnDefType Type;

        date_t *Adress;
        date_t Default;
        DateFormat Format;
        static date_type init(date_t *p, date_t nDef, DateFormat fmt) { date_type t = {T_date, p, nDef, fmt}; return t; };
    };

    template <typename T, ColumnDefType E>
    class numeric
    {
    public:
        ColumnDefType Type;

        T *Adress;
        T Default;
        static numeric<T, E> init(T *p, T nDef) { numeric<T, E> t = {E, p, nDef}; return t; };
    };

public:
    ColumnDef(void) { mType = T_UNDEFINED; }
    ColumnDef(ubyte_type const &t) { mType = t.Type; ub = t; }
    ColumnDef(date_type const &t) { mType = t.Type; d = t; }
    ColumnDef(cpp_string_type const &t) { mType = t.Type; cps = t; }
    ColumnDef(cstring_type const &t) { mType = t.Type; cs = t; }
    ColumnDef(numeric<size_t, T_size_t> const &t) { mType = t.Type; st = t; }
    ColumnDef(numeric<byte_t, T_byte> const &t) { mType = t.Type; b = t; }

    virtual ~ColumnDef(void)
    {
    }

    void func(ColumnDefType nType)
    {
        switch(nType)
        {
            case T_byte:
            {
                byte_t *p = b.Adress;
                if(!p)
                    break;
            }
            break;

            case T_size_t:
            {
                size_t *p = st.Adress;
                if(!p)
                    break;
            }
            break;

            case T_ubyte:
            {
                ubyte_t *p = ub.Adress;
                if(!p)
                    break;
            }
            break;

            default:
                std::cout << "Unknown" << std::endl;
            break;
            }
    }

private:
     ColumnDefType mType;
     union
     {
        ubyte_type ub;
        date_type d;
        cpp_string_type cps;
        cstring_type cs;
        numeric<size_t, T_size_t> st;
        numeric<byte_t, T_byte> b;
     };
};

int main()
{
    std::string s = "value"; 
    date_t dt;
    char tst[5];
    size_t n;
    byte_t b;

    // Correct examples
    ColumnDef c0(ColumnDef::date_type::init(&dt, 0, ColumnDef::DF_YYYY_MM_TT));
    ColumnDef c1(ColumnDef::cstring_type::init(tst, sizeof(tst)));
    ColumnDef c2(ColumnDef::cpp_string_type::init(&s));

    ColumnDef c3(ColumnDef::numeric<byte_t, ColumnDef::T_byte>::init(&b, 0));
    ColumnDef c4(ColumnDef::numeric<size_t, ColumnDef::T_size_t>::init(&n, 0));

    // Wrong intialization causes a compiler error because type doesn't match enum. Only T_size_t should be allowed here.
    ColumnDef c5(ColumnDef::numeric<size_t, ColumnDef::T_std_string>::init(&n, 0));
    ColumnDef c6(ColumnDef::numeric<size_t, ColumnDef::T_byte>::init(&n, 0));
    ColumnDef c7(ColumnDef::numeric<size_t>::init(&n, 0));          // should assign the correct type automatically inferred by the supported type

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do the same thing, but with different enums: `ColumnDef::numeric<size_t, ColumnDef::T_std_string>::init(&n, 0)`, `ColumnDef::numeric<size_t, ColumnDef::T_byte>::init(&n, 0)`, based on what concrete value from `enum` should be selected?

Comment: Yes, this is just to demonstrate the wrong initializations, which should result ina  compiler error. However, what I want to achive is that if given like c7 the correct type is inferred by a template. I'm currently trying to use enable_if but I don't really understand it.

Comment: So when I use the enum T_size_t, size_t is the only allowed type (or the other way around if that makes it easier). i.E. when I give a size_t type, it should select T_size_t as the enum type.

Comment: This is screaming to me that you need to templatize `ColumnDef`. But that would also require program rearchitecture on a pretty large scale, cause it means that anything `ColemnDef` is passed to must also be templatized. What you're really making here is a container. Enums to describe a contained type is a C tactic. Note all standard containers simply `typedef` their contained type. If you're interested in tackling the rest of the architectural changes I can type up a templatized `ColemnDef` for you.

Comment: Is there something you want (functionally, performance wise, notationally?) that `boost::variant` doesn't already do well, or is this a learning exercise?

Comment: @JonathanMee, this is a conversion from C code. :) I was hoping to get away with a helper class which is the templatized version, so I don't need to change the underlying class ColumnDef. It is already an improvement that I got typesafety with the above code, but I find it ugly that I have to specifiy the correspondance between enum and type each time individually.

Comment: @TonyD, it's not an exercise. I'm looking now into this boost:variant, because on first look it seems pretty similar to what I try to do here. :) Using boost in the code is currently not an option.

Comment: @Devolus I'd say it's time to complete the improvement. If this is a hack then there was little reason to improve the code from the C version in the first place. If however this is something designed to be longterm maintainable, it should be moved to C++ templates. I would strongly recommend against the halfway approach you have here. You *will* spend longer trying to work around the problem than you would to fix it in the first place. And your resulting code will be far less maintainable.

Comment: @JonathanMee, Actually your comment got me thinking... I guess what you say is true, but I have to wrap my head around it, to see how much effort this will be. In the long run it's definitely the better approach.

Comment: @Devolus I'm excited to hear you say that. C++ code makes the world a better place. If you post questions along the way, I'd love to help. Feel free to link me in a comment here!

Comment: @JonathanMee, Changed now the design to make ColumnDef a virtual base class, and got rid of the ugly type/switch idiom. Took me a few days, but it's much better now IMO because it's more natural extendible this way,without having a multitude of parmeters around to acount for all combinations. :)

Comment: Excellent work sir. If the world were filled with programmers such as yourself we'd have probably already achieved peace in our time. I'd give you a +1 for encouragement but I've already given you one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write map between types and enum values, and then reuse it in your code:

```
namespace details {
    template <typename T> struct TypeToEnum;
    template <>
    struct TypeToEnum<size_t> {
        static const ColumnDef::ColumnDefType value = ColumnDef::T_size_t;
    };

    template <>
    struct TypeToEnum<char> {
        static const ColumnDef::ColumnDefType value = ColumnDef::T_byte;
    };
}

template <typename T>
ColumnDef::numeric<T> ColumnDef::numeric<T>::init(T *p, T nDef) 
{
    ColumnDef::numeric<T> t = {details::TypeToEnum<T>::value, p, nDef};
    return t; 
}
```

Comment: I knew that I had to use some helper templates, but I didn't get it, how to implement it, as I'm still rather new to the more advanced template techniques. :) Can you explain why there is the `template<>` needed?

Comment: `template<>` is specialization of template for concrete type, so `TypeToEnum` defined only for `size_t` and `char`, and all other variants cause compile time errors.